# Operators in OCaml

Tags: operators, ocaml

I created a module like this:

```
module Foo = 
struct
   class foo =
   object(this)
   ...
   end
   let (><) (f1:foo) (f2:foo) = ... 
end
```

After that I opened this module in a different file and tried to use operator ><, but ocamlc threw an error: "Error: Unbound value ><", but in utop this operator works right.

```
open Foo
let x = new Foo.foo;;
let y = new Foo.foo;;
let z = x >< y;;
```

Maybe this problem connected with options to ocamlc, I compiled like this

`ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core Foo.ml test.ml -o main`

where Foo.ml is a file with module Foo, test.ml contains usage of operator.

So, does OCaml support this way of using operators or I made something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a module named Foo defined in a file named Foo, the name of the inner module is `Foo.Foo`. In OCaml the outermost level of a file forms a module named after the file.

You can say `include Foo.Foo`. Or you can remove the module `Foo` wrapper from the file `Foo`.